# HTML5 Form Submission Equivalent $.post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I'm working on a small web app and I have it to a point where I can input data into a form, click a button, and delete that data from a form. I'd like to be able to just click on the data in a table and have it do a similar function, i.e. somehow use $.post to post the data instead of making the form do it. I'm at a loss of how to do it though. I've read several tutorials and articles and am at a loss of how to replicate the form's submit functionality.

Here's my current way of doing things via form/php:

**The Form Template**

```
<form name="DeleteMarker" action="index.php" target="_self" method="post">
             <fieldset class="Splice">
                <legend>Delete Marker</legend>
                    <label>Employee: </label><select name="DEmployee">
                    <label>Job Name: </label><select name="DJob">
                    <label>Customer Name: </label><select name="DCustomer">
                    <br>
                    <label>Latitude: </label><input name="DLatitude" min="-180" max="180" step="0.00001" required />
                    <label>Longitude: </label><input name="DLongitude" min="-180" max="180" step="0.00001" required />
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

**The PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['DEmployee'])) {
        $sql="DELETE FROM Splices WHERE (Employee='$_POST[DEmployee]' AND Job='$_POST[DJob]' AND Customer='$_POST[DCustomer]' AND Latitude=$_POST[DLatitude] AND Longitude=$_POST[DLongitude])";
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$Splices)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
```

I have a javascript function where a click on the table will display an alert, I just need to figure out how to put a $.post or $.ajax statement in there to replicate the functionality of the form I already have.

**The (incorrect) javascript I have:**

```
function deleteRecord(e,j,c,l,ln) {
        confirm("Delete Record ("+e+", "+j+", "+c+", "+l+", "+ln+")?");
        if(confirm){
            $.post("index.php", {DEmployee:e, DJob:j,DCustomer:c,DLatitude:l,DLongitude:ln});;
        }
}
```

Comment: This is not HTML5, it is jQuery

Comment: what happens when you run the function what isn't working? is the call being made? what is contained in the form? have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Daniel - what happens when I do anything of this ilk is that the page either simply doesn't load or that my php doesn't catch the data posted in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not mention about jQuery, but $.post is an available method on jQuery. if you are using jQuery and include it to your page it's ok. than you can do that like this,

```
$('form[name=DeleteMarker]').submit(function() {
  var dataString = $(this).serialize();
  $.post("index.php", dataString);
  return false;
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Actually your `deleteRecord()` function has some other incorrect usage.

`confirm()` returns a boolean(true or false), so you have to use this returned value to continue your code.

`if(confirm) {}` is not right way to do it,

you must use it like,

```
var c = confirm("do you confirm?");
if(c) {
   //yes it's confirmed.
}
```

or more useful,

```
if(confirm("do you confirm?")) {
   //yes it's confirmed.
}
```

---

you said '**the url is still just "index.php"**', how did you look that, I don't know but it's normal, because the method is not GET, so url will not include posted data as querystring. If it doesn't work, there might be some other problem.

---

---

**EDIT-2:**
Actually there is no differences between them, ok here is a full example, you can look your browser javascript dev-tool to see what's happening on background.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['DEmployee'])) {
        $sql="DELETE FROM Splices WHERE (Employee='$_POST[DEmployee]' AND Job='$_POST[DJob]' AND Customer='$_POST[DCustomer]' AND Latitude=$_POST[DLatitude] AND Longitude=$_POST[DLongitude])";
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$Splices)) {
            echo "Error:  ". mysql_error();
        } else {
            echo "employee deleted";
        }
  } else {
        //you can add something else here
        //<div>blablabla</div>
        //and the form for delete
?>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $("form[name=DeleteMarker]").submit(function() {
                if(confirm("This will be deleted, are you sure?")) {
                    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
                    $.get("index.php", dataString ,
                        function(data){
                          alert(data);
                    });
                } 
                return false;
            });
         });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form name="DeleteMarker" method="GET">
             <fieldset class="Splice">
                <legend>Delete Marker</legend>
                    <label for="DEmployee" >Employee: </label>
                    <select name="DEmployee">
                      <option value="name1">name1</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="DJob">Job Name: </label>
                    <select name="DJob">
                      <option value="job1">job1</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="DCustomer">Customer Name: </label>
                    <select name="DCustomer">
                      <option value="cusname1">customer name1</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label>Latitude: </label><input name="DLatitude" min="-180" max="180" step="0.00001" required />
                    <label>Longitude: </label><input name="DLongitude" min="-180" max="180" step="0.00001" required />
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: A novel idea, but for some reason it doesn't put the serialized string in the URL, the url is still just "index.php". I'm wondering if having it inside a "confirm" does anything?

Comment: @Sean if you are still using your own deleteRecord(), it might be wrong, see my updated answer again.

Comment: I only have the one page, so I want it to happen on the same page. If $.get would be better, how would construct the request and get it in the php?

Comment: Thanks for the persistence, but this latest edit doesn't account for a table element being clicked on. I tried to edit this in but have been thus far unsucessful

Comment: @Sean I can't say anything about your edited code, without seeing it, but I tried the latest one, it's working.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume from your use of $.post that you're using jQuery, even though you didn't tag it.  Luckily, jQuery does all the work for you:

```
$.post("index.php", $("form[name=DeleteMarker]").serialize(), function(data) {
    //Do something with the response here
}).error(function() {
    //Do something in the case of an error here
})
```

Comment: So under the hood, this is what submitting form data via a button push does? What is that argument "$("#DeleteMarker").serialize()"? I'm trying to get rid of the form all together and just use jquery

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

You should still keep the form - ideally, you want the page to still work if the user has javascript disabled.  Using $.post just allows you to be fancier.

Comment: @Sean DeleteMarker is not id, the correct one $("form[name=DeleteMarker]")